# Websphere Class not found exception with deployment assembly project

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I have created a ear project.I have add a one project as deployment assembly project.but when i publish my project on WebSphere then server return class not found exception which is place in Deployment assembly project.

When i export ear file as .ear then jar file is placed in web project lib folder.But it is not running.

But if i am place the deployment assembly project as jar and place them in websphere/lib/ext folder and then start server it is running fine for me.But this is not right way.

Please can any one help me.

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.project.ClassFileName
[10/7/15 19:02:39:128 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:128 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:250)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:128 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.sterling.reporting.model.ReportFactory.getInstance(TestFactory.java:13)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:128 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.sterling.reporting.view.ReportController.getReport(DemoDemoController.java:179)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.actions.MappingDispatchAction.execute(MappingDispatchAction.java:169)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:129 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(DemoClass.java:1114)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:130 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:131 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:131 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:131 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:131 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:131 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:131 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[10/7/15 19:02:39:131 IST] 00000075 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

This is printstack of exception.

Comment: Can you share the sample EAR? Pls post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari i have update our question with stacktrace,